# Is it safe to design a web page where logout functionality is done through clicking a link instead of a form button?

Tags: html, gmail, csrf, logout

I have come across many articles which warn against *using links to provide logout functionality*. They all recommend using a form and button for logout.

When I used firebug to examine the html for gmail's logout element,I found that it is a link:

```
<a target="_top" role="button" id="gb_71" onclick="gbar.logger.il(9,{l:'o'})" href="?logout&amp;hl=en" class="gbqfbb">Sign out</a>
```

The `href` has something like

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/?logout&hl=en
```

Are they using a link because the `href` is https? How safe is this usage?

Comment: What were the reasons those articles gave for avoiding using links?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that recommendation. Many of the web apps I use provide a standard url (e.g. /logout) for logging out, and a link pointing at that URL. Any change you could provide a link to one of those articles? I'm curious.

Comment: I couldn't find the article link in my bookmarks, but there was a case when a crawler plugin installed in the machine( for exploring all links in html pages) used to click the logout link and thus log out the user.So the article recommended use of form and button

Comment: Also,I guess a csrf attack from site2 can take an authenticated user (of  site1) to click on a innocuous looking link on site2 which is actually  a link with 'site1/logout'

Comment: http://www.squarefree.com/securitytips/web-developers.html#CSRF

Comment: The article you linked to doesn't mention directly why it would be a problem. One potential problem: an attacker wants to steal your login information for site1, so he sets up site2 that spoofs site1, forces a logout on site1, then gets you to log into site2 instead of site1 when you log in again, thus turning over your account details. That example is a tad complex of a way to phish, but it could happen if you're using a link or a button.

Comment: its make no difference that you are click on link or button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that developers are discouraged from using links, rather than forms, is because it leaves a site open to CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) attacks. Imagine you have a site, and the logout URL is `example.org/?logout`. If you visit my site, and I load that URL, it will log you out of your current session on example.org. This does not seem destructive, but it is rather annoying to have to keep logging in.

Now imagine it where you have implemented it as a form...

```
<form action="?logout" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" value="blahblah" name="key" alt="I am a random key!" />
  <input type="submit" value="Log out..." />
</form>
```

The value of `key` would be randomly generated on the loading of the page. When the url `example.org?logout` is loaded, it checks the session to make sure that the random key is the same as that submitted by the form. If it is not the same, the user may not log out. If it is the same, they may.

This simple method stops the described CSRF attack. It is simple and effective, and there is really no reason NOT to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing unusual to use a GET to logout users. Anyway, this is a bad practice. For example, if you are logged in Gmail account, visit [this page](http://jsbin.com/izusiy) to see the "result". And, it does not matter HTTP or HTTPS.

But, this trick do not work for Stackoverflow `http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout`. Anyway, better to logout user, is to use a POST request or random token:

```
http://site.com/logout?token=123456
```